# Ember.js - how to handle a dynamically built layout?

Tags: ember.js

Say I have an array of views [header, menu, list, aside, bottom, footer] which is not fixed, but set up dynamically, so the array elements could be different. What I would like to achieve is to render all this in some way, something like this:

```
for (view in views) {
   view.render(model, controller);
}
```

This is not a valid Ember code, I just made it up to be able to explain my question. 
I have checked the Ember.ContainerView and Ember layouts, but those don't seam to offer anything similar.

Can I do something like this the Ember way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the following does what you describe:

```
views.forEach(function(view) {
  view.set('controller', controller);
  view.set('content', model);
  view.append();
});
```

This appends the views to the document body. You can supply a selector to `view.append()` to render into a particular element.

That said, an approach using `CounterView` is certainly more Ember-idiomatic and has the added benefit of tearing down your views when the parent view is removed. There is more information in the [Ember.js guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/manually-managing-view-hierarchy/).